# Angular bootstrap date range component not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to display [angular bootstrap range datepicker.](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/range/plnkr.html) on click event. right now it just open 2 months datepicker and fill up only 1 date.

how do I make the [demo](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/range/plnkr.html) working on click

```
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" [displayMonths]="displayMonths" [navigation]="navigation" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
      <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
    </button>
```

Below code is working fine if I am not using range date picker. 
ts code

```
  import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
  import {NgbTypeahead} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
  import {NgbDateStruct, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';



  const equals = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
    one && two && two.year === one.year && two.month === one.month && two.day === one.day;

  const before = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
    !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
      ? false : one.day < two.day : one.month < two.month : one.year < two.year;

  const after = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
    !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
      ? false : one.day > two.day : one.month > two.month : one.year > two.year;



  const country = ["United States", "China", "Japan", "Germany", ]
  const nationality = ['American', 'Indian', 'Japanese', 'Chinese','Spanish'];
  const hotel_name = ['American', 'Indian', 'Japanese', 'Chinese','Spanish'];
  const select_city = ['saberia', 'kirtipur', 'ohiocity', 'gama','alpha'];
  const select_location = ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4','location4'];

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-accommodation',
    templateUrl: './accommodation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./accommodation.component.css']
  })
  export class AccommodationComponent {

hoveredDate: NgbDateStruct;

fromDate: NgbDateStruct;
toDate: NgbDateStruct;

constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
  this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
}

onDateChange(date: NgbDateStruct) {
  if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
    this.fromDate = date;
  } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && after(date, this.fromDate)) {
    this.toDate = date;
  } else {
    this.toDate = null;
    this.fromDate = date;
  }
}
 isHovered = date => this.fromDate && !this.toDate && this.hoveredDate && after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.hoveredDate);
isInside = date => after(date, this.fromDate) && before(date, this.toDate);
isFrom = date => equals(date, this.fromDate);
isTo = date => equals(date, this.toDate);




displayMonths = 2;
navigation = 'select';
```

Please guide me to make this working for [angular bootstrap range datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)